# gsp mail plugin autosending

Tags: grails, controller, grails-plugin, gsp

When I navigate to the page, why is the send() function being called automatically?

I want to be able to view the gsp page, fill in a few text fields, and THEN call the submit with an action of "send"

This is my gsp file

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
<title>Contact Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<g:form name="contactForm" action = "send">
    <g:render template = "contactFormFields"/>
    <g:actionSubmit value = "submit" action = "send"/>
</g:form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the contactFormFields template

```
<g:select name = 'subject' from = '${EmailService.options}' noSelection='Topic'/>

Contact Name: <g:textField name = "contact"/>
Contact Number: <g:textField name = "phone"/>
Contact Email: <g:textField name = "email"/>
Aditional Information:
<g:textArea name = "information" rows="5" cols="40"/>
```

EmailServiceController

```
class EmailServiceController {

    def defaultAction = "contactService"

    def send() {
        sendMail(){
            to "mygroovytest@gmail.com"
            from params.email
            subject params.subject
            body params.information
        }
    }
}
```

domain class

```
class EmailService {

    static constraints = {
        def options = new ArrayList()
        options.push("Qestions about service")
        options.push("Feedback on performed service")
        options.push("Other")
        options.push("Why am I doing this")
    }
}
```

gsp that calls the service

```
<div class="banner">
  <h1>My HVAC company</h1>
  <a href = "javascript: contactPop()"> Contact me today!</a>
  <a href = "services">Services</a>
  <a href = "emailService">Have Me Contact You!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more context about which action is loading this form?

Comment: @uchamp I added the domain class and the div where the link lies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `contactService` action in your `EmailServiceController` so it's probably treating `send()` as the default action when you link to the controller with no action name.  Try adding an empty `contactService` action

```
def contactService() { }
```

Comment: good catch, but now it's saying options has to be a set (which I don't know how to do yet).  I was trying to use grails to simplify the processes, which it has, but I'm learning it's a whole new beast

Comment: @MattWestlake as written above you've declared `options` as a local variable inside the `constraints` block of your domain class (which incidentally is very badly named - you should only really use the `Service` suffix for services, not domain classes).  I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but if the list of options is fixed then it's probably easier to either declare them inline in the GSP or put them in an enum in `src/java` rather than trying to use a domain class.